# Dans la construction verbale « V + Inf » suivante peut -on insérer « pour » et si oui quel est l'effet produit ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes

J'ai lu dans  mon livre de grammaire qu'après certains verbes, si un autre verbe suit, il faut l'utiliser à l'infinitif et directement à la suite. Par exemple:

> Il est sorti acheter du pain

Mais, puisque l'implication est qu'il est sorti *afin d'* acheter du pain, je voudrais dire

> Il est sorti **pour** acheter du pain.

Donc je me demande si les deux sont corrects, et si oui, pourquoi utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre.

(Aussi, personnellement, je crois qu'il est plus courant de dire, « il est allé chercher du pain » ; est-ce que cette façon de parler serait celle conseillée parce que ce serait une façon de parler plus simplement ?)

Comment: Les phrases sont construites pour évoquer un contexte : « Il est sorti acheter du pain » ([on pourrait ajouter] "et faire d’autre courses") — « Il est sorti **pour** acheter du pain » ([et rien d’autre], "puis est rentré chez lui *pour* le manger"). —   « Il est sorti **pour** acheter du pain » (et [aussi] **pour** … ). *Pour* diminue l’espace de la sortie dans le contexte de la question, mais ce n’est pas une règle, juste une nuance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En effet les deux formulations sont entièrement correctes.
La petite différence entre les deux phrases est ce qui est mis en avant.
Dans la phrase "je suis sorti chercher du pain", l'information la plus importante est le fait que "je" sois sorti.
Dans la phrase "je suis sorti pour chercher du pain", donc en utilisant la préposition de but "pour", on met en valeur le but, donc ici, le fait d'aller chercher son pain. Dans cette phrase, "chercher du pain" est d'importance égale voire supérieure à "je suis sorti".

Comment: Très clair, merci

Answer (score 1):

Dans le document « *Le lexique des constructions verbales - CIEP* », dont un format pdf est disponible, et qu'il est utile de consulter entièrement puisqu'il fournit une classification de ces constructions en 19 classes, on trouve que la construction considérée est dans la classe II : N - Vmvt - Vo - Comp (nom, verbe de mouvement, verbe à l'infinitif suivi d'un complément ou non).

Il  est indiqué que dans ces constructions que le sujet doit pratiquement toujours être humain et que la construction avec « pour » fournit une paraphrase, c'est à dire que les deux constructions sont entièrement synonymes.

[image]

Les considérations suivantes montrent les limites de cette construction.

[image]

Il n'y a donc aucune raison d'utiliser la forme avec « pour »  plutôt que celle sans et les deux sont du même registre de langue.

Est-il préférable de dire « allé chercher » ?

L a réponse n'est pas courte mais, foncièrement, c'est non.

Lorsque vous dites « Il est allé chercher du pain. » vous utilisez la même  construction (classe II). Il n'est pas préférable de dire « aller chercher » plutôt que « sorti acheter » ; les actions exprimées résultent en un même état de chose qui est seulement considéré selon des  aspects différents mais impliquant la même fin : pour sortir il faut aller et si l'on va chercher du pain, le contexte étant qu'il est entendu qu'il n'y a pas de pain au logis et que l'on ne va pas le chercher dans la cuisine pour l'amener dans la salle à manger, il faut sortir; de même, acheter du pain  implique que l'on doit aller le chercher et vice versa.

L'action « allé chercher » « couvre » « sorti acheter » et c'est une action générale qui dans la vie humaine  occurre beaucoup plus  ; il est donc normal que par rapport à « sorti acheter » la fréquence soit très faible, ce que montre cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=19&content=all%C3%A9+chercher%2Csorti+acheter&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%C3%A9%20chercher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorti%20acheter%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Call%C3%A9%20chercher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorti%20acheter%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Cependant, cela n'est pas une indication de non idiomaticité de « sorti acheter » ; utiliser cette dernière forme plutôt que « aller chercher » ne confère pas au locuteur un plus grand formalisme, ne place pas son élocution dans un registre de langue différent ; la seule différence est la spécificité des termes et celle-ci peut être considérée comme appropriée. C'est au contraire « allé chercher » qui manque en spécificité; comme déjà expliqué ci-dessus, vous pouvez vous trouver dans la salle à manger, manquer tout à coup de pain et si vous dites de la personne qui s'est levée de table et est allée dans la cuisine pour prendre du pain « Elle est allée chercher du pain. » vous ne dites pas du tout que cette personne est sortie pour acheter du pain : il s'agit seulement d'aller chercher ce pain dans la cuisine.

Il se trouve que votre intuition est vérifiée dans le cas du complément « pain » ; cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=19&content=all%C3%A9+chercher+du+pain%2Csorti+acheter+du+pain&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%C3%A9%20chercher%20du%20pain%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Call%C3%A9%20chercher%20du%20pain%3B%2Cc0) le prouve.

[image]

Cela se comprend comme le pain en France est une denrée alimentaire qui se consomme dès qu'elle vient d'être fabriquée et comme il est nécessaire de se déplacer quasiment tous les jours pour avoir du pain bien frais; cela résulte en une forme linguistique correspondante très usitée qui se trouve être « allé chercher », mais cela ne signifie pas que ce soit la seule qui soit idiomatique ou la seule qui ne donne pas l'impression que le locuteur ne parle pas bizarrement, pas du tout. Il n'y a aucun doute, vous pouvez utiliser « sorti acheter » sans crainte de paraitre bizarre ou de ne pas être compris.

Il y a dans la [recherche suivant](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sorti%20acheter%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) un grand nombre d'utilisations de « sorti acheter » qui montre que c'est une forme tout à fait normale du point de vue usage. Il est seulement nécessaire de consulter un certain nombre de ces exemples pour s'apercevoir que c'est une forme du langage courant. Il est certain que dans beaucoup des exemples on pourra aussi dire « aller chercher », mais il n'y a aucun principe interdisant d'utiliser « sorti acheter » dans le cas du pain : étant donné que les actions sont exactement du même type  ce serait très irrationnel.

Comment: Wow merci pour tous les détails! C'est tellement interessant.

Comment: @DerekAllums j'ai moi-même appris certaines choses en me penchant sur cette question.